# Facebook Graph API since/until and pagination

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I'm using graph api to periodically query messages from a facebook conversation. On each query I'm passing since parameter (since last query time) and getting the data. What I'm expecting is that when I pass since it's only returning the new data since the time I'm passing, however it still sends a pagination link which leads to old data. Is this intentional or a bug?

Comment: This is intentional, because `since` primary purpose _is_ to be used for pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem here. It looks like next in pagination is generated despite the fact that it leads to old records. Perhaps "manually" checking if the records are older than since/until is the way to go?

Also read this article by [Jeff Bowen](https://www.facebook.com/jeff.bowen) from Facebook about [pagination in Facebook Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/).